# What is the smallest number n of positive distinct integers to guarantee that at least 15 of them are congruent mod 7?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help figuring out how to do this question. I am not sure if set of given distinct integers is specifically the first n elements of the natural numbers set, but I assume that otherwise this question would have no solution.

Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: By some version of the pigeon-hole principle. it seems like it should be $7*14+1$ since then at least one equivalence class mod $7$ would have to have at least $15$ items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $7$ distinct congruence classes. Worst case scenario is that you get $14$ distinct elements for each congruence class, i.e. $14 \times 7=98$. Then the $99$-th element will make one of the classes with $15$ distinct elements, so the answer is $99$.

In general if you want to find the smallest number of distinct positive integer to guarantee that at least $k$ of them are congruent mod $m$ is $(k-1)\times m+1$.